# Flask-GoogleMaps api key argument and scroll_wheel not working

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I am using [Flask-GoogleMaps](https://github.com/rochacbruno/Flask-GoogleMaps/blob/master/README.md). I have succesfully implemented it but with a workaround so Flask-GoogleMaps gets my API key.

The documentation is simple and I am pretty sure that it is a bug but just in case I ask, probably I am doing something wrong.

Currently I need to use this aswell to get my API key, I simply add the standart script line proposed by google. If I don't use this I get an error No-Key-Error and the map doesn't show:`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>`

Because I am using Flask-GoogleMaps I need to implement this file in my template:

`{{ mymap.js }}`

This file is used to load all styles for the map and also loads/expects a key. But if I enter a key this way:

`GoogleMaps(app, key="MYKEY")`

or in my config.py

`GOOGLEMAPS_KEY = "MYKEY"`

It won't recognize the key, which leads also to a No-Key-Error. I can't delete mymap.js because then the map doesn't show, if I delete the script the map won't show + No-Key-Error.

So currently I need to use both, the mymap.js and the script line, which leads to "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page" but still works. Also I cant disable the scroll_wheel. I am setting up the map in python:

```
mymap = Map(
    identifier="view-side",
    lat=location.latitude,
    lng=location.longitude,
    infobox=[],
    markers=[],
    scroll_wheel = False,
    zoom = 11
)
```

The scroll_wheel = False does not do anything here, eventhough I found it in the documentation.

I give mymap then to the view and use {{ mymap.html }} to load the html.

The best solution would be to pass the key to Flask-GoogleMaps and remove the script line.

Here is the live example: [My Website](https://www.monteurzimmer-1a.de/details/dortmund-3). Ignore the initautocomplete error, it's already fixed.

Comment: the option is "scrollwheel" not "scroll_wheel"

Comment: yes if you use it in google's javascript I know, but not in Flask-GoogleMaps: https://github.com/rochacbruno/Flask-GoogleMaps/blob/master/flask_googlemaps/__init__.py